# Apache HttpClient: set timeout for NoRouteToHostException

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-timeout

I am using Apache HttpClient 4.2.5 and need to set connection timeout for 30 seconds. I do the following:

```
int timeout = 30 * 1000;
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, timeout);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, timeout);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url.toURI());
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, timeout);
client.getParams().setParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, timeout);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

But after 12 seconds NoRouteToHostException is thrown form client.execute(request). As I understand, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and SO_TIMEOUT is useless here. Have you any idea, how to set timeout for NoRouteToHostException? I should hope that server became available within this time. Thanks for any comment and advice!